# Check if each object of list is present in another list

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

I have two lists of same class:

```
class Test
{
int A;
String B;
Char C;
}

Element of two lists are:

List<Test> obj1 :

1   “Abc”   'a'
2   “Bcd”   'b'

List<Test> obj2:

1   “Abc”   'a'
2   “Bcd”   'b'
3   “Cde”   'c'
4   “Def”   'd'
5   “Efg”   'e'
```

I want to check if rows of obj1 is present in obj2. For example first two rows of obj1 is in obj2. I have achieved this using loops. Can anyone help me in doing the same through linq query or without loops. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`, or create custom comparer for your objects, then you can project both lists into anonymous objects:

```
obj1.Select(t => new { t.A, t.B, t.C })
    .Except(obj2.Select(t => new { t.A, t.B, t.C })
    .Any();
```

If your lists share same instances of objects, then simply (it will compare objects by references)

```
obj1.Except(obj2).Any()
```

You can use this approach if you will add `Equals` and `GetHashCode` implementations to your class (see sample of implementation below). Also you can create comparer for your test classes:

```
public class TestComparer : IEqualityComparer<Test>
{
    public bool Equals(Test x, Test y)
    {
        return (x.A == y.A) && (x.B == y.B) && (x.C == y.C);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Test obj)
    {
        int hash = 19;
        hash = hash * 17 + obj.A.GetHashCode();
        hash = hash * 17 + obj.B.GetHashCode();
        hash = hash * 17 + obj.C.GetHashCode();
        return hash;
    }
}
```

And pass this comparer to overloaded [`Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336390%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
obj1.Except(obj2, new TestComparer()).Any()
```

Comment: It would probably be faster to use `Join`, e.g. `obj1.Join(obj2, t => new { t.A, t.B, t.C }, t => new { t.A, t.B, t.C }, (t1, t2) => true).Any();` instead of `Except`.

Comment: @DominicKexel not sure about that - `JoinIterator` creates `Lookup` for inner sequence, and then iterates over outer sequence. `ExceptIterator` does same, but uses `Set`

Answer (score 3):

If your lists share the same instances of objects (you can see @lazyberezovsky's post for overriding `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods) you can use LINQ `Any`. This will return `true` if an item in `obj1` is in `obj2`:

```
obj1.Any(obj => obj2.Contains(obj));
```

*EDIT*

If I misunderstood you (as some commenters suggested) and you want to check if all objects in `obj1` are present in `obj2` you can use LINQ `All`. This will return `true` if all items in `obj1` are present in `obj2`:

```
obj1.All(obj => obj2.Contains(obj));
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be All()?

Comment: @jdv-JandeVaan No, that would require that `All` the elements in `obj1` are in `obj2`. He just wants to know if any of them are.

Comment: @gleng I think jdv is right, the question was:
I want to check if rows of obj1 is present in obj2.

Comment: @Wasafa1 I disagree. Any row from obj1 present in obj2 = `Any`. All rows in obj1 present in obj2 = `All`.